# Knob Widget (or alternative) in PyQtGraph

Tags: qwt, pyqtgraph

I'd like to port Eli Bendersky's application written for PyQwt over to PyQtGraph... doing this mostly to learn and because it's unclear if Qwt or PyQwt is actively maintained (trying to avoid potential issues getting it to work with my PyQt5 / Python3.4 installation)

So the example uses a Knob widget, however I don't see much of control widgets looking at the (2?!) PyQtGraph documentation sites,
http://pyqtgraph.daffodil.uk.com/
http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/

Is there a way to use Qwt's Knob widget in PyQtGraph?   If not, can a a similar custom widget for PyQtGraph be made?

Comment: Qwt maintenance and development is alive, but pyQwt is unmaintained and got stuck with Qwt 5.x several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

- Qt already provides a dial widget: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdial.html
- If this is not sufficient, then making a custom widget is certainly an option, and the Qt docs have plenty of information on that topic.
- Is is of course possible to use any Qwt widgets with pyqtgraph, but you will need PyQwt for this (which defeats the purpose of the exercise).

Regarding documentation: pyqtgraph.org hosts the official documentation, whereas daffodil.uk is hosting some proposed modifications to the documentation from another developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but someone interested with qwt might help.

- qwt is currently maintained. Can be found here https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/PythonQwt.
- This is python 3 port Eli Bendersky's [live serial plotting application](https://github.com/q-eldar/pyserial_plot).
- There is no knob widget in new version qwt (haven't found), but you can you QDial instead.

  ```
   self.dial = QDial()
   self.dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
   self.dial.setRange(0,20)
   self.dial.setValue(10)
   self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.on_dial_change)
  ```

Comment: Python bindings for current Qwt versions can be found here: https://github.com/GauiStori/PyQt-Qwt.